# How to improve message processing with large queues?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to use Spring JMS and ActiveMQ to process a large number of messages. The context of the problem is the following:
Each customer produces a set of messages that are added to the queue. The messages are added to the queue with the customer id as parameter.

In one case, customer A can add 10k messages to the queue, while customer B only adds 100 messages to that same queue. My issue is customer B needs to wait until all the 10k messages have finished processing before its 100 messages are processed.

Is there a way to process some of messages of customer A and some of the messages of customer B at the same time? I know there is the option to set a higher priority on the messages from customer B, but that does not solve the issue when there is more multiple customers. The customer with the more messages will fill-up the queue while the others will have to wait.

I would appreciate if you could provide some help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have find the solution to the issue. It involves using message groups. For each message I set the property JMSXGroupID with an identifier for the customer.

Since they are multiple message groups the queue takes care of assigning messages from different groups to different consumers. In that way, documents from customer B can be processed while the ones from customer A are still being processed.

Comment: The queue's semantics are still FIFO. In other words, the messages from one group cannot be processed before the messages in the groups in front of it.

Comment: I agree this @JustinBertram, it is still FIFO. However I have made changes to the application processing workflow. Customer A and customer B are still there however I create small batches of 10 messages that are associated with a message groups. As a result messages from custormer A and B can be processed at the same time. The 10k messages from A will be fan out in 100 groups while the 100 messages from B will be fan out in 10 groups. In theory the groups are processed by different consumers so messages from A and B should be processed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The basic semantic of a queue is first-in-first-out (i.e. FIFO). There's no real way to escape that. I recommend you redesign your application to use multiple queues - one for each "type" of message or independent application you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about dynamically creating queues for each customer. The issue with that option is I don't see how to list the queues using the JMSTemplate. Also Do you know if it is possible to dynamically assign a consumer to a queue. From what a see a consumer is always associated with a given queue.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Spring's JMSTemplate. My impression is that it's good for a narrow set of use-cases, but it's not very flexible. I could be wrong about that. I recommend you create a new question to get an expert to provide some guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback  @Justin Bertram

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can fine tune your activemq the number of messages it is processing in batches. Also, there are way you can fine tune a given Broker and queue. For more details refer this link:

http://activemq.apache.org/performance-tuning

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html-single/ActiveMQ_Tuning_Guide/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, however this does not really help. This would only help in processing messages faster, not in processing different customers at the time.